# I want to know if it is possible to divide two strings

Tags: c#

I have two strings

`FractionOne` which has a value of lets say 33
`FractionTwo` which lets say has a value of 1

for example racing odds 33/1

I'm trying do convert them to `decimal` by doing `FractionOne` divide by `FractionTwo` and adding 1

the answer should be 33

and converting it back to a `string` (Maybe) and displaying it in a `TextBox.text` on my form...

this is where I get it from

```
var GetFractionOne = new Regex(@"(?<=class=""desktop-hdn"">SP )(.*?)(?=/)").Matches(set);
var GetFractionTwo = new Regex(@"(?<=[0-9]/)(.*?)(?=</strong>)").Matches(set);
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Why should `33 / 1 + 1` be 33?

Comment: what is the value of `GetFractionOne` or `Two`?

Comment: sorry, my mistake...it should be 34

Comment: GetFractionOne is 33

Comment: GetFractionTwo is 1

Answer (score 2):

```
double val = (double.Parse(FractionOne) / double.Parse(FractionTwo)) + 1;
```

Comment: this is where I get the values from..                var GetFractionOne = new Regex(@"(?<=class=""desktop-hdn"">SP )(.*?)(?=/)").Matches(set);
                var GetFractionTwo = new Regex(@"(?<=[0-9]/)(.*?)(?=</strong>)").Matches(set);

Comment: You forgot to add `1`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Fixed.

Comment: @SeanProbyn `GetFractionOne` and `GetFractionTwo` will be of type `MatchCollection` then, and won't be able to get parsed. You'll need to get the string value with an indexer or use the `Match` method of Regex instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your values are string-types. To do arithmetic calculations on them you have to use a number-type, in your case `double`. Thus use [`Double.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) or - when you´re sure the values *are* numbers and can´t be anything else - also `Double.Parse`:

```
double f1;
double f2;
double result;
if(Double.TryParse(GetFractionOne, out f1) && Double.TryParse(GetFractionOne, out f2))
{
    result = f2 / f1 + 1;
}
```

Alternativly you can also use [`Convert.ToDouble`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.110).aspx).

Both, `Convert.ToDouble` and `Double.Parse` will throw an exception when the provided argument is not convertible to a double. `Double.TryParse` however simply returns `false` in this case.

Comment: what if my string was "33/1"

Comment: Do you want to create a calculator? This isn´t trivial, iamgine what happens if user enteres `33 + 1.5`. Anyway you´re question was on two numbers stored in strings, not on a whole calculation stored within one string.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0103 The name 'FractionOneToString' does not exist in the current context ...fractionOneToString was called earlier in the program is there a way to bring it back